# Xamarin Forms PCL - Missing references

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I created the project on a Windows system but when i needed to compile and test it for iOS I moved it into a Mac, when I'm testing and deploying into an a real device (iPhone) it works fine, but when I try to archive it, Visual Studio throws an error (Pic 1) saying that I'm missing some references, and I'm, but only on Shared and Android Projects (Pic 2).

I'm also including log of the archiving process (Link 1).

Thanks in advance,
Pedro Martins

[Pic 1][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUE1q.png
[Pic 2][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaILw.png
[Link 1][3]
[3]: https://justpaste.it/4ziiq

Comment: Somehow you have a `Xamarin.Android` reference in your iOS project, you need to remove that reference as it 1) not needed and 2) will cause problems for archiving

Comment: @SushiHangover can it be because i'm using a Dependency Service? If not where else can i search for such reference.

Comment: No... Double click on the `References` in Solution Explorer of the **Xamarin.iOS project** and remove the Xamarin.Android reference.

Comment: @SushiHangover there is no Xamarin.Android Reference on Xamarin.iOS project

Comment: Looking at the `Pic 1`, it looks lookout might be your NetStd project then, the top of it is cut off so the Project name is not shown...

Comment: @SushiHangover should i remove those references? If i do that it's going to break things for android no?

Comment: A PCL/.NetStd library project can not have a direct assembly reference to Xamarin.iOS|Android, the other way is fine, a Xamarin.iOS|Android application/library project can direct reference a PCL/.NetStd assembly. Surprised is actually is working in Android, but I bet you do not have the Mono linker turned on

Comment: @SushiHangover got it working, thank you for the information :D